# Retreive set subject line

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am creating multiple emails based off the same template in ExactTarget. Some of the emails will have a different subject line. Is there any way to pull the subject line created during the initial creation of the email?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, so I'm going to paraphrase and see if I understand:
1.  You create an email.
2.  You later save this email as a template.
3.  You create a new email off this template, but want to use the original subject line of the original email.
Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Sorry - I edited this to include ExactTarget, since you had AMPscript listed.  Is this a Salesforce email, or an ExactTarget email?  Can you provide a bit more info to clarify?

Comment: @Timothy - sort of.
I have a template built and I am creating emails based off the template. When creating an email based off a template, you know how you enter a subject, well, how do I get that entered subject line?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews I know how to do dynamic subject lines but looking for an ampscript code to grab the subject line that is enter when creating a new email.

Comment: At what point are you trying to retrieve it? During the send, after the send?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews - from my experience with other variables, it populates after the send.

Comment: What I am asking, is what are you specifically doing with the subject line. With out a code sample here, or any further information, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews - Sorry this is confusing.
My Process:
Log into ExactTarget.
Click Create.
From Create Dropdown, select Template Based.
Template (popup choose template)
Email Name (Enter Value Name email)
EMAIL SUBJECT (ENTER VALUE FOR SUBJECT)* -- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO GRAB
Save.

After that, I want to set the *Email Subject i created in the process above to the title tag in the HTML therefore, I need a variable. 
Ex.
%%[
 var ATSubject,
 Set ATSubject = emailsubject
]%%
<title>%%=v(ATSubject)=%%</title>

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is no, you cannot grab the subject line in the email context.

You can however, set the subject line to be a variable, and set that variable in the context of the email.

For example, set your subject line to `@SubjectLine`, and in the email, set that as normal:

```
set @SubjectLine = "My Catchy Subject Line"
```

You can use that in your title as well, if need be.

Comment: I suppose if you store the subject line in the send log,  you could technically get it that way.  There just isn't a quick method like %%subjectline%% or something.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and this is how i solved it using a `content area and AMPSCript`:

1. Create a new `content area`
2. Create your `AMPSCRIPT logic` in the `content area` for example:

   ```
   %%[
   SET @subjectline1 = "My Subject Line"

   SET @SC = TEST

   if (@SC = TEST) then
   SET @subjectline1 = "My New Subject Line"
   endif


   ]%%

   %%=v(@subjectline1)=%%
   ```

3: Place the `content area` in the subject line section: `%%=ContentArea("52483")=%%` You will need the `Content area id`.

Comment: Why not just script this in the body of the email instead of using a Content Area?  The Content Area seems like unneeded overhead.