# Capture subject line in send log

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, logging

I'm trying to capture the emails subject in the send log. Is there any way for me to do this?

**To the 'experienced' community members:** Not sure how to rephrase this any better. Maybe you could tell me what exactly is unclear so I can clarify. Yet I'll try anyway.

I created a [send log](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/) Data Extension with the following Fields:

`JobID, ListID, BarchID, SubID, TriggeredSendID, ErrorCode, view_email_url.`

I'd like to add another field like, 'subject' which represents the subject of the particular email being logged / sent. However, I am unable to capture that information. It doesn't look as if any of the [personalization strings](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/) can be used.

@[Kelly-J-Andrews](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/4786/kelly-j-andrews) hints at the ability to do this in the comment on the [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/31112/16462).

Comment: I have reopend the question, do understand that some effort is expected to be put into a question. Your update has made it clear that this is about the marketing cloud, so i've taken the liberty to add that to your question (tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously suggested, you could use an AMPScript variable for your subject.

```
%%[ 
var @subject 
set @subject = "This is the subject" 
]%%
```

In your send definition the subject would be: `%%=v(@subject)=%%`

In your Send Log DE, you'd have to have a column named "subject"

If you'd rather not use the Send Log and email scripting, the subject is available in the [System Data Views](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_job/) and is accessible via [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).

For a particular send, you can query the `EmailSubject` and `DynamicEmailSubject` columns.  I'd recommend building your query starting with _Job and then inner joining to _Sent based on the JobID (aka the SendID from the Tracking tab).  I typically use _Job.PickupTime to narrow it down by date.  Something like this:

```
select
j.emailName
, j.EmailSubject
, j.DynamicEmailSubject
, s.SubscriberKey
, s.EventDate
from _job as j with (nolock)
inner join _sent as s with (nolock) on (s.jobid = j.jobid)
where j.pickuptime >= dateadd(day,-7,getdate())
```

You can also join this back to your Send Log if you'd like (by JobID).

Comment: Since adding the subject to the send log directly seems to be unsupported and a hack -- I'm going to attempt to get the data as you suggest by a Query Activity. So far, here is the query I have: 
select
asl.IID
, asl.view_email_url
, j.DeliveredTime SendDate
, j.EmailSubject Subject
from ArchiveSendLog asl
inner join _job j with (nolock) on (asl.jobid = j.jobid)

Comment: That works.  Setting the subject line with scripting is not as uncommon as you might think.  It happens quite a bit in multi-lingual emails.

Comment: Makes sense, do you know if the EmailSubject column of the _job system view will contain the dynamic subject line or the ampscript?

Comment: It'll contain the AMPScript, yes.