# Retrieve Email Subject from AMPSCRIPT in SFMC

Tags: email, ampscript, marketing-cloud

Is there a way to retrieve the Email subject from AMPScript?
According to the documentation, it seems I can retrieve only the name and id with the following statements:

%%_emailid%%

%%emailname_%%

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [Retreive set subject line](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30993/retreive-set-subject-line) ??

Comment: Can you provide a use-case where you'd need to retrieve the subject line via AMPScript?

Comment: I would like to put the subject line in a querytrstring parameter for tracking. For Example: if I insert "EMAIL SUBJECT" in the subject text box, I would like to take this parameter and put it in a querystring... something like this: http://www.example.com?t=%%=v(@SubjectLine)=%%

Comment: Mr Frodo, thanks for your reply but it's not my scenario: I don't want to write the email title in AMPScript, I would like to use the UI because the Email creation is done by collegues without technical skills end I would like to creare a template which captures the subject. I don't now why it seems there is not a dedicated personalization string  such as %%subjectline_%% or something similar

Answer (score 0):

There's no [Personalization String](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization/) for the subject line, however, you can always make it a variable, pass it in the [Web-Analytics Connector](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/) or write it to the [Send Log](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/).

**In the body of the email**

```
%%[
var @subject
set @subject = "This is the subject"
]%%
```

**In the subject**

```
%%=v(@subject)=%%
```

**In the WAC**

```
?subject=%%=urlencode(@subject,1)=%%
```

Send logging has to be enabled by SFMC Support.  The Web Analytics Connector also has to be enabled and/or updated by SFMC Support.

**Reference**

[URLEncode()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/http/URLEncode.html)

Comment: Is Adam's answer still the best approach with regards to using 'Subject' with WAC?
(Any chance this is available to retrieve from the 'Subject' input box in the content editor now?!?).